# What part of a blackberry bush do I plant to make a new bush

Tags: planting, blackberry, berries

I have a breed of blackberry bush in my backyard that is unlike any other blackberries I've had in the past and I'd very much like to plant more just like it. What part of the plant do I need to plant to make a new bush and what's the best way to do this?

**Added photo as requested:**

[image]

Comment: Could you please post a picture so we can see exactly which plant you are asking about? Some propagation advice is plant or season specific. We can better advise you if we can see the plant.

Comment: Just to avoid disambiguity:  are we talking about bramble (rubus) or mulberry (morus nigra)? Both go by the name "blackberry". I'd like to answer, but it should fit the plant in question.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details - I don't actually know what type the blackberry bush is. Hopefully the picture helps - this breed seems to have far more thorns than the others I see more commonly in the area and this one's berries are much larger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we're talking about commonly referred to Rubus, most plants in the genus can be propagated 3 ways, by cuttings, by sectioning off suckers - the easiest if there are suckers present already, or by tip layering - burying the tip of a stem a few inches below ground to encourage the plant to produce a sucker.

Comment: When I bury a tip of a stem is there any type of stem that is better, such as one with a bud... also, is now a good time to plant it or is there a more ideal time of year?

Comment: Spring would be the best time. There's a whole involved method here (the second one). Not sure you need to go to all that effort, especially for something as aggressive as a blackberry, but it gives you the general idea. http://nipomonativegarden.org/plantinfo/layerings.shtml